# Java object pointers

Tags: java, android

I have android Java program, i need common function to modify rootA or rootB by setting rootList to the one i want to modify.

```
  public List<String> rootList=new ArrayList<>();
  public List<String> rootA=new ArrayList<>();
  public List<String> rootB=new ArrayList<>();
  public index;

  public void f1()
  {
     select(rootA,3);
     select(rootB,2);
  }

  public void select(List<string> ary, int x)
  {
      rootList=ary;
      index=x;
      func1();
  }

   public void func1()
   {
      rootList.remove(index);
      rootList.add("hello");
   }
```

Functions f1, select, and func1 are all in different classes, and rootList, rootA, rootB, index, are global, i just put in all here for clarity.

I want to be able to call f1, and have it modify rootA or rootB using the same functions by just setting rootList to either rootA or rootB. Will this work or do i need to do it some other way?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "are global"?

Comment: Global to the whole program, stored in a singleton.

Comment: Please give us code that shows the methods and fields in their original classes, not "just put in all here for clarity", as that doesn't improve clarity, but makes your question very unclear.

Comment: The main point is to be able to modify RootA or RootB by setting rootList to either rootA or rootB, which class the functions are in dont matter

Answer (score 0):

Pass the list you want to modify, along with `index` and any other information needed, as parameters of `func1`. This eliminates the need for global state, which is evil in general and particularly evil on Android.

Comment: my question is, if i set rootList to rootA, then in the function i do rootList.remove(2) will that remove item 2 from rootA?

Comment: @PaulPatt Yes, but it's horrifying spaghetti code. You can't tell what the function is doing just by looking at the function, which makes the code much harder to maintain. (And to split hairs, "function" is the wrong word. You seem to have written a static method, though you didn't make it `static`.)